# Show Individual Versus Group Performance

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to do something I feel should be fairly easy, which is showing Individual vs. group performance. I have a relatively simple set of data for revenue by 10 agents split by 2 teams:

Sample Data Set

```
Agent       Team      Revenue
Agent 1     Team A    1000
Agent 2     Team A    500
Agent 3     Team A    800
Agent 4     Team A    600
Agent 5     Team A    400
Agent 6     Team B    700
Agent 7     Team B    600
Agent 8     Team B    600
Agent 9     Team B    800
Agent 10    Team B    1000
```

I want the end user to be able to select an agent and then see the revenue from that agent and compare to the agents entire team. So for example, if I selected Agent 1, I'd like to see:

Output result

```
Agent Dollars     Team Dollars
1000              3300
```

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to add what have you tried so far for future questions. It will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a calculation called 'Team Dollars' as below. (This uses a FIXED LOD)

   `{FIXED [Team]:SUM([Revenue])}`

   [image]
2. Build the view as below

   [image]